# Do digital payments count as cash wages?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, cash, employment

According to [Publication 926 (2019), Household Employer's Tax Guide](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p926), "Cash wages include wages you pay by check, money order, etc."

Do cash wages also include wages I pay electronically, ie, without paper, eg, with PayPal, credit card, cryptocurrencies, etc?

Comment: How do you pay wages with a credit card?

Comment: @DStanley, if your household employee accepts credit card, eg, via Square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, yes, since those are just *platforms* to transfer funds.

Non-cash wages would include things like lodging (meaning you provide lodging, not pay for lodging someone else provides), food, clothing, etc. that have utility other than as a means of currency exchange.